Analysis of microarray data (GSE76720) using limma package in R. Error: row dimension of design doesn't match column dimension of data object
Here is the code i was trying to use and which worked untill this point, unfortunately I am not able to solve this problem in any way. I tired out various code alteration proposed by various AI and searched forums but nothing works currently. Can you please help me solve this problem?
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)) install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("limma")'

library(limma)

URL = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/files/E-GEOD-76720"
SDRF.file = "E-GEOD-76720.sdrf.txt"
Data.file = "E-GEOD-76720.zip"
download.file(paste(URL,SDRF.file,sep="/"), SDRF.file)
unzip(Data.file)

SDRF <- read.delim("E-GEOD-76720.sdrf.txt",check.names=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Treatment = SDRF$FactorValue[treatment]

levels = c ("transfected with siRNA targeting lncVSM for 24 hours","transfected with scrambled siRNA for 24 hours")

Treatment = factor(Treatment, levels=levels)
x = read.maimages(SDRF[,"Array Data File"], source="agilent", green.only=TRUE, other.columns="gIsWellAboveBG")
dim(x)

if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("HsAgilentDesign026652.db")

library(HsAgilentDesign026652.db)

x$genes$EntrezID = mapIds(HsAgilentDesign026652.db, x$genes$ProbeName, keytype="PROBEID", column="ENTREZID")
x$genes[1:nrow(x$genes),]

y = backgroundCorrect(x, method="normexp")
y = normalizeBetweenArrays(y, method="quantile")
Control = y$genes$ControlType==1L

NoSymbol = is.na(y$genes$Symbol)

IsExpr = rowSums(y$other$gIsWellAboveBG > 0) >= 4

yfilt = y[!Control & IsExpr, ]

dim(yfilt)

yfilt$genes = yfilt$genes[,c("ProbeName","EntrezID")]

head(yfilt$genes)

design = model.matrix(~Treatment)
fit = lmFit(yfilt,design)

row dimension of design doesn't match column dimension of data object
#The rest of the code I wanted to use:
fit = eBayes(fit,trend=TRUE,robust=TRUE)
summary(decideTests(fit[,-1]))

I tried creating a vector out of the Treatment factor, checked the length and dimensions of each part and tried to make them equal, but even if i accomplished it, the same error occurred. I couldn't find any solution on the forums or in various AI i would greatly appreciate your help with solving this problem as I am fairly new to R programming.
